# Custom HTML5 video player

Tags: javascript, css, html, video

I want to create a custom HTML5 video player sort of like youtube. The seekbar is created using input `type="range"` and a custom slider thumb(round). Now, the problem; How to fill the lower half of seekbar with a color ?

- Successfully done in FireFox. using -moz-range-progress
- Microsoft edge also supports this, but now my slider thumb is not
            visible (just a bar and not the circle).using -ms-fill-lower.
- Not supported in Chrome (headache!!).

I want to create it using only the input element. Thanks a lot in advance !!

Comment: Short answer .. you can't! If there's no cross-browser support, you can't magically create browser support, you have to find another way to do it, for instance with regular elements that look like a slider. Why not just look at the source code for some players that do what you want, and see how they solved it.

Comment: yeah !! .. I guess thats what i have to do now. Thanks for your time.